# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/default/bumblebee'

Tags: bumblebee

I got this problem, I don't know how to solve it ... Please help me.

```
$ sudo bumblebee-app-settings   
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/usr/local/bin/bumblebee-app-settings", line 37, in <module>
    import Config   File "/usr/local/bin/app/Config.py", line 69, in <module>
    [default_compression]=[re.sub(r'VGL_COMPRESS=(.*)\n', r'\1', line) for line in open(config_file_path) if 'VGL_COMPRESS' in line] IOError:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/default/bumblebee'
```